# DOMDocument can't get all of my records from database

Tags: php, dom

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once ('../includes/connect.php');
try {
    $filter = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
    $check = $filter->rowCount();
    echo $check.'<br />';
    for($i = 1; $i < $check+1; $i++){
        $c = $filter->fetch();
        //echo $c['ID'];
        $source = file_get_contents($c['pURLMorele']);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($source);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

        $rows = $xpath->query("//span[@class='price']");

        print_r($rows->item(0)->textContent);
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Something went wrong!<br>'.$e->getMessage();
    die();
}
?>
```

In my database are 4 records, but i don't know why it's showing me only 3 of them (2, 3 ,4). Where is 1?!

This is my output:

```
4
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/20/147910/webspace/httpdocs/serwer151299580.twojeaz.pl/functions/pricesUpdate.php on line 19
515,00 zł 269,00 zł 1589,00 zł
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing:

```
for($i = 1; $i < $check+1; $i++){
    $c = $filter->fetch();
```

to

```
while($c = $filter->fetch()){
```

That way you're not exceeding the bounds of the resource.

Comment: Okay, thanks :)
But still, can't get 4 records, only 3 :(